# Do I need to unsubscribe from a GestureRecogniser in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So I have the following Control, extended from `Label`

```
public Hyperlink()
{
    var tapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_Tapped;
    this.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
}
```

Now my question is, do I need to unhook the `GestureRecogniser`?

My understanding of **GarbageCollection** is that because the `Hyperlink` object is in charge of the `tapGesture` it should be able to dispose of it; but this is the world of Xamarin.Forms where anything goes.

So do I need the `Dispose` code to avoid a potential memory leak and avoid keeping the object alive

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (this.GestureRecognizers.Count > 0)
    {
        var tapGesture = this.GestureRecognizers[0] as TapGestureRecognizer;
        tapGesture.Tapped -= TapGesture_Tapped;
        this.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
    }
}
```

[This link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16970/gesturerecognizer-should-manually-remove), as well as [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/a-journey-of-hunting-memory-leaks-in-xamarin) say that I should be removing `GestureRecognisers` but does not expand on why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Cross-Platform Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/memory-perf-best-practices), suggest you unsubscribe from GestureRecogniser.

> To prevent memory leaks, events should be unsubscribed from before the subscriber object is disposed of. Until the event is unsubscribed from, the delegate for the event in the publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds this reference, garbage collection will not reclaim the subscriber object memory.

Comment: @user1, anything update? If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you use persistent pages, you do not need to manually dispose of your gesture recognizer. it will be destroyed when whatever page was using it is popped and collected by GC.

If it puts you at ease, you can still manually dispose of it and it won't hurt anything, but it is not required.